# Why do we need something like _tag property on Option type in tp-ts?

Tags: typescript, functional-programming, fp-ts

I'm looking at Option type in [fp-ts](https://github.com/gcanti/fp-ts) library. From its definition, we have an internal property `_tag` on the Some and None interfaces.

https://github.com/gcanti/fp-ts/blob/master/src/Option.ts

```
interface None {
  readonly _tag: 'None'
}

interface Some<A> {
  readonly _tag: 'Some'
  readonly value: A
}

type Option<A> = None | Some<A>
```

What is the purpose of this property. Is this for using [Discriminated Union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-func.html#discriminated-unions) feature of TypeScript and pattern matching, or are there any other reasons for it?
Can we use Symbols in JS ES6 instead of `None`?

Comment: Without the authors opinion, we can only guess, but typechecking through discriminated unions seems to be quite a strong case. And yes, using symbols instead would work just as well.

Answer (score 2):

In this case it's not so much a question of distinguishing `None` from `Some<A>` because `Some<A>` has a `value` field and `None` doesn't.

The "problem" with standardising algebraic data types is that ADTs sharing the same features also share the same structure (`Functor` has a `map`, `Monad` has `chain`, `Foldable` has `reduce`, and they all look the same). TS is structurally typed, so if you had no discriminant, you could mix and match ADTs, which is not correct (like concatenating 2 different semigroups)

This implementation does not use classes, so you can't rely on a `private value` to use as a discriminant, hence the tag.

Answer (score 0):

The answer that I finally feel happy with is pretty simple.

We have a Sum Type for `Option`. meaning `None` and `Some(...)` are 2 different things that share a concept of Optionality.
We somehow need to differentiate them using our language and tools (which here is TypeScript).

When we are pattern matching over `Option`, We can either check for existence of for example `value` property on the object to decide if we are looking at a `Some` or not, or we can introduce a consistent internal property `_tag` to do that.
Well choosing a consistent property like `_tag` that helps us to leverage from the existing useful features of TypeScript like *Discriminated Union* is a no-brainer to me.